# How to print a sequence of Strings column wise?

Tags: java, string

I was trying to write a program in Java for a game I was designing; wanted to have a part in the game which imitated LED lighting. But the sequence I wanted to print has to be printed column wise only (from left to right).

The sequence is going to be ASCII art:

```
db   db  d888888b 
88   88    `88'   
88ooo88     88    
88~~~88     88    
88   88    .88.   
YP   YP  Y888888P
```

and the printing should be done like this:

```
d b
8 8
8 8 o o o
8 8 ~ ~ ~
8 8
Y P
```

Each of those columns should be printed one after the other, in front of each other.

Comment: Sorry, but, I couldn't deduce the pattern from the problem-statement! Please,do you mind clarifying logic?

Comment: what is your text type?String ?char array? etc.if string did you try split("\n"); then split each line by split("");

Comment: what i meant was that i need to display the columns one after the other...You  know the LED sequences right...one vertical strip lights up then the next, and then the next, and so on which gives an illusion of movement of the strip...like that.

Answer (score -2):

Make a print method for each character by using the following print statement and call the required one when necessary.

example 
    public void printXXX(){
    // xxx replace character
    System.out.println("d  b");
    .
    .
    .
    so on....
    }